# Automating drawing sine wave and similar drawings

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code to draw some graphs. In this example, a sine wave.

How can the code be modified to say

(previous x + a value, previous y + a value)

instead of repeating defining the x,y coordinates manually in each location?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,red,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0)
 sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0)
 sin (5,1) cos (6,0) sin (7,-1) cos (8,0)
 sin (9,1) cos (10,0) sin (11,-1) cos (12,0)
 sin (13,1) cos (14,0) sin (15,-1) cos (16,0)
 sin (17,1) cos (18,0) sin (19,-1) cos (20,0)
 sin (21,1) cos (22,0) sin (23,-1) cos (24,0)
 sin (25,1) cos (26,0) sin (27,-1) cos (28,0)
 sin (29,1) cos (30,0) sin (31,-1) cos (32,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0)
 sin (1,1) cos (2,0) sin (3,-1) cos (4,0)
 sin (5,2) cos (6,0) sin (7,-2) cos (8,0)
 sin (9,3) cos (10,0) sin (11,-3) cos (12,0)
 sin (13,4) cos (14,0) sin (15,-4) cos (16,0)
 sin (17,5) cos (18,0) sin (19,-5) cos (20,0)
 sin (21,6) cos (22,0) sin (23,-6) cos (24,0)
 sin (25,7) cos (26,0) sin (27,-7) cos (28,0)
 sin (29,8) cos (30,0) sin (31,-8) cos (32,0)
 sin (33,7) cos (34,0) sin (35,-7) cos (36,0)
 sin (37,6) cos (38,0) sin (39,-6) cos (40,0)
 sin (41,5) cos (42,0) sin (43,-5) cos (44,0)
 sin (45,4) cos (46,0) sin (47,-4) cos (48,0)
 sin (49,3) cos (50,0) sin (51,-3) cos (52,0)
 sin (53,2) cos (54,0) sin (55,-2) cos (56,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\foreach` and relative coordinates: `\tikz[scale=.5] \draw[ultra thick,red,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0) foreach \i in {1, ..., 8}{ sin ++(1,1) cos ++(1,-1) sin ++(1,-1) cos ++(1,1) };` and `\tikz[scale=.5] \draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm] (0,0) foreach \i in {1, ..., 14} { [y=1cm + 1cm*((\i < 9) ? (\i-1) : (15-\i))] sin ++(1,1) cos ++(1,-1) sin ++(1,-1) cos ++(1,1) };` (this one could also be solved by chaing `yscale` or the *y* value of each coordinate).

Comment: @– Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you for your code.

Comment: @Hany Are you asking about the beat phenomena ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beat_(acoustics)

Comment: @ Black Mild Is there a TikZ code for it!

Comment: The TikZ code would be to plot the function.  Your blue wave would be something like 5sin(x)sin(30x).  But you've not helped us really understand what you're doing.  You've told us that most of our suggestions won't help for your actual plots, but you've not told us why or what those plots are.  And Qrrbrbirlbel's gives your red and blue, but then you completely ignored the foreach in your answer.

Comment: @ Teepeemm  As I`ve mentioned in my post, what I am looking for is how to simplify the tikz code to be something like (previous x + a value, previous y + a value) instead of repeating defining the x,y coordinates manually in each location. I do not want to use the plot. I need a code concept that could be applied for other curves. Using the sin/cos is just a simple example that presents my idea. Using ++, as proposed by Qrrbrbirlbel, solved the problem to a great extent.

Comment: @ Teepeemm I came up with the following code to draw the needed drawing: \tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=8-abs(8-\x);}}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xinc}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yinc}{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,-16) foreach\i in {1,...,15}
  {sin ++(\xinc,{\yinc*f(\i)}) cos ++(\xinc,{-\yinc*f(\i)}) sin ++(\xinc,{-\yinc*f(\i)}) cos ++(\xinc,{\yinc*f(\i)})};

Comment: @ Teepeemm I also use the code proposed by Qrrbrbirlbel.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

**Edit:**

- To my opinion, composing (smooth) functions as follows from showed examples, with some universal scalable "building boxes", is dead end ... after few building boxes you will stack with problems, not visible now, for example how to connect them in smooth function.
- Better is to use `plot` function, accordingly define function and their domain. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
trig format=rad,
ultra thick, red, 
domain=-8*pi:8*pi, 
samples=601             ]
%
\draw   plot (\x/4, {sin(2*\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
trig format=rad,
ultra thick, blue,
domain=-8*pi:0,
samples=801             ]
%
\draw   plot (\x/4,{((8*pi-abs(\x))/(2*pi))*sin(2*\x)});
    \end{tikzpicture}

\bigskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
trig format=rad,
ultra thick, blue,
domain=-8*pi:8*pi,
samples=801             ]
%
\draw   plot (\x/4,{(sin(\x/4))*(sin(4*\x))});
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum (1):**
In the case, that you persist to stick to function chunks ordered in some chain, you can define chunks as scalable "boulding boxes" (BB) and then positioning them in image by use of some loop or `chains` library.

Is this what you after?

An example of chain of a simple BB ordered by loop:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
BB/.style = {draw=teal, fill=teal!30, 
             minimum width=1cm, minimum height=\h cm,
            }
                        ]
\foreach \i in {-3, -2,...,3}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{int(3-abs(\i))}        % calculation of function
    \node[BB=\h] at (\i,0) {$\i$};
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
One more example, by using `chains˛library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=0pt,
  start chain = going right,
BB+/.style = {on chain,
             minimum width=1cm, minimum height=\h cm,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                          \draw[ultra thick,line join=round,line cap=round,red] 
                                (\LN.west) -- (\LN.north) -- (\LN.east);}% end \pgfextra
                         }% end append after command
            },
BB-/.style = {on chain,
             minimum width=1cm, minimum height=\h cm,
    append after command={\pgfextra{\let\LN\tikzlastnode
                          \draw[ultra thick,line join=round,line cap=roundred,blue] 
                                (\LN.west) -- (\LN.south) -- (\LN.east);}% end \pgfextra
                         }% end append after command
            }
                        ]
\foreach \i in {-3, -2,...,3}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\h}{2*int(3-abs(\i))}        % calculation of function
\ifthenelse{\isodd{\i}}
        {\node[BB+] {};}
        {\node[BB-] {};}
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I pointed out before, this is just an example; I can not use plot for my other drawings. So, as I mentioned in my question, I would like to say (previous x + a value, previous y + a value) so that the code can be applied for other drawings.

Comment: @Hany, you can not have universal/common node for all your diagrams. Using plots and define functions which you like to draw, is a way to go ...

Comment: @– Zarko Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 3):

I'm no sure what exactly you are doing in your example, but in principle this kind of stuff can be automated using pgf's `\foreach` (automatically available when using tikz).

However, normally you'd use the `\draw plot` command to plot stuff inside TikZ or - if you want a "proper" plot - simply skip to using pgfplots in the first place:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, x=0.5cm, y=1cm, ultra thick, red]
        \draw (0,0)
            \foreach \x in {0,4,...,28}{
                sin ({1 + \x}, 1) cos ({2 + \x}, 0) sin ({3 + \x}, -1) cos ({4 + \x},0)
            }
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[domain=0:12,samples=100] plot ({\x}, {sin(deg(\x))})     ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot[samples=100] {sin(deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I said, this is just an example to be applied for other drawings. Unfortunately \addplot can not be used in my other drawings. How can I use your \foreach solution to draw the blue wave?

Comment: @Hany what's the definition of the blue wave's shape?

Comment: The blue wave in my question.

Comment: @Hany yeah that much is clear. But you must have had some sort of formula to get those points. what's that formula?

Comment: @– Raven I just want to modify my code for using your solution. Or to use your idea to be applied in other drawings. Thank you.

Comment: @Hany see my edited answer. That should be enough to do arbitrary paths based on that scheme.

Comment: @– Raven Applying your \foreach code gave me the following drawing https://i.stack.imgur.com/aabB8.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145442/discussion-between-raven-and-hany).

Comment: Do you test your suggestion? Can us show result of your test?

Comment: @Zarko yes I did test my suggestion but I didn't consider it worth to include the actual output. This is about the concepts that can be used to solve the problem at hand and not about producing pretty images.

Comment: Sorry, your code is misleading. Its result is a mess, consequently it not help anyone. Consider to provide useful code, if not is better to delete your answer.

Comment: The code is useful in that it provides different methods how OP's task can be automated. I just didn't do it for them.

Comment: The first `\foreach` using `\draw (0,0) sin ({1 + \x}, 1) cos({3+\x}, -1);` seems totally useless here, it's not producing any kind of sine wave, just drawing lots of lines each running between just three points.  The edit should probably replace it as technically, the most immediate "automation" of what the OP is trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the code of Qrrbrbirlbel, I came up with this solution; which can be used for scaling the sine wave as wanted.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xinc}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yinc}{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,red,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*1)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*2)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*3)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*4)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*5)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*6)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*7)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*8) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*8) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*8) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*8)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*7)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*6)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*5)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*4)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*3)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*2)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*1)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In both other answers are code for producing showed image significantly shorter, less prone to errors ...  Apparently you like to invent a wheel again ...

Comment: @– Zarko Thank you very much for your addendums. No, I do not like to invent a wheel again. As I said before, I would like to come up with a short code that could be applied for other drawings, as well as for the sine wave; which is only an example for what I have in mind.

Comment: @Hany But you should be able to use your relative coordinates approach with a `\foreach` loop to greatly simplify things.  Or is your actual example too complicated for that.  (And if you leave off the `-` from the `@`, then SE can properly notify the people.  It will offer to autocomplete the name if you're doing it correctly.)

Comment: @Teepeemm Thank you for your comment.