# Automating a scalable sine wave code

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

From the answer to [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683342/automating-drawing-sine-wave-and-similar-drawings), inspired by the code of [Qrrbrbirlbel`s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683342/automating-drawing-sine-wave-and-similar-drawings#comment1695484_683342), I came up with this solution; which I posted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683342/automating-drawing-sine-wave-and-similar-drawings/683490#683490).

Now how can I use \foreach loops to automate this solution?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xinc}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yinc}{1.5}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,red,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\vskip 1cm
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*1)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*2)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*3)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*4)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*5)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*6)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*7)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*8) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*8) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*8) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*8)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*7) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*7)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*6) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*6)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*5) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*5)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*4) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*4)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*3) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*3)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*2) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*2)
 sin ++(\xinc,\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc*1) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc*1)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you are bringing questions that are of interest to me.

Comment: @anis Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd go for a `\draw plot` for this because, joining sines and cosines with different scales we wet a non-smooth function.

(**Update:** I added a couple of `\draw plot` versions too).

That said, you can do something like this. The first sine is pretty straightforward, but for the second you need (for example) to declare a function that compute the increments:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1.618mm]{standalone}
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=8-abs(8-\x);}}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\xinc}{1.}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\yinc}{1.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5, transform shape]
\draw[ultra thick,red,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,0) foreach\i in {1,...,15}
  {sin ++(\xinc,\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,-\yinc) sin ++(\xinc,-\yinc) cos ++(\xinc,\yinc)};
\draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] (0,-16) foreach\i in {1,...,15}
  {sin ++(\xinc,{\yinc*f(\i)}) cos ++(\xinc,{-\yinc*f(\i)}) sin ++(\xinc,{-\yinc*f(\i)}) cos ++(\xinc,{\yinc*f(\i)})};
% with \draw plot
\node at (16,-30) {\huge with \verb|\draw plot|:};
\draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] plot[domain=0:64,samples=1001] (\x,{-40+f(0.25*\x)*sin(104*\x)});
\draw[ultra thick,blue,x=0.5cm,y=1cm] plot[domain=0:64,samples=1001] (\x,{-56+7*sin(2.8*\x)*sin(104*\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S.: you have too many scale factors (`\xinc`,`\yinc`,`scale=.5`,`x=0.5cm`,`y=1cm`). Are you sure you need all of them?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I mentioned in my original previous post, using sine wave is just an example for what I want to do for other drawings. I needed a short code that could be applied for them too.